# Why is Fermat's spiral formula written as $r^2=a^2\theta$ instead of $r=a\sqrt{\theta}$?

Tags: notation

I'm reading *Clifford A. Pickover's* Math Book, in the Fermat's spiral page, it says the Fermat's spiral formula is $r^2=a^2\theta$, why isn't it written as $r=\pm a\sqrt{\theta}$? What's the problem in writing it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aesthetics: polynomial equations are usually nicer to work with. Probably a bit of tradition.

Also, $r = a \sqrt{\theta}$ is only half the spiral anyways: the other half is given by $r = -a \sqrt{\theta}$.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that when I evaluated it on Mathematica, to be precise, it would be $r=\pm a\sqrt \theta$.

Comment: Can you comment about **usually nicer to work with**?

Comment: It's one of those self-evident things that are hard to put words to. Solving for one variable as a function of the other frequently leads to much more complicated formulas, which is a hinderance in the common situation that you don't actually need things expressed that way.

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 2):

The standard form works for all $a$ and $\theta$. It also eliminates the need to consider the different branches of the square root.